# USE Amazon Product Advertisement API by ajax requests

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, amazon-web-services

I am trying to use **amazon product advertisement api** using javscript for **browser**.

My moto is to make **ajax calls** to **amazon api server** to get response XML.

I have done request from server using curl already.

But I want/thinking to make it from **`browser`**.

I use sign Helper provided by amazon to create *REST URL/SIGNED URL*.

But when I put that url in **ajax and fire request**.

It says:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   http://ecs.amazonaws.com/onca/xml?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAI27C4W24NJCLCJCQ&Assoc…=2011-08-01&Signature=6qTYdd%2FSRh%2BHAG8x2SiLb%2FukNx9ks.
>   No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://example.com' is therefore not allowed access.

So Anybody have idea about it. How to make this possible?

Or somebody who done it already?

Also can we request for Json Response?

Comment: use your server server as proxy

Comment: You mean to say, send ajax request to server and get response from there. Am I right? Because from server this is possible.

Comment: Yes  see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3076414/ways-to-circumvent-the-same-origin-policy